# Triple to pair point-free way

Tags: haskell, pointfree

Here is a function that multiplies the first two elements of a three-elements tuple:

```
f (a, b, _) = a * b
```

I was curious if it was possible to make this function point-free. For a pair that would be as simple as `f = uncurry . (*)`, and if we had something like [`tripleToPair`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/graphite-0.10.0.1/docs/Data-Graph-Types.html#v:tripleToPair), that would make the solution obvious, but that function is also written the most straightforward way, via pattern matching.

I asked the almighty [pointfree.io](http://pointfree.io/), but it returned error 500. Is that even possible? The question is purely theoretical, in my opinion, the function is good as it is.

Comment: When moving to pointfree, we usually choose the set of primitives we allow. The "usual" set of primitives deals with pairs, only. E.g., why do we have `curry/uncurry` for 2-argument functions, only, and not in general? In some languages, a triple is represented as a nested pair `(a,(b,c))`, and there dealing with pairs suffices to be general, but Haskell uses a completely distinct type to gain efficiency, so I guess we need to allow some more primitives in our pointfree transform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is with `liftA2` (ab)using the `Applicative` instance for functions

```
import Control.Applicative

-- This two functions are defined in module Data.Tuple.Extra from extra package
-- You could use lenses too, I guess
fst3 (a,_,_) = a
snd3 (_,b,_) = b

f = liftA2 (*) fst3 snd3
```

Comment: I thought there could be some magic using the base package, but this is nice. Having `extra`, we could also do `f = uncurry3 (const .) . (*)`, but it's less elegant.